# Rails sum all prices inside a record

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a model `Products` that `belongs_to` model `Kit`

Kit `has_many` `Products`

¿How can I sum all of the prices of each product that belongs to a kit?

**I tried with no luck:**

```
@kitprice = Kit.products.price.sum
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
@kitprice = kit.products.sum(:price)
```

In my case i have wallet with many operations

```
wallet = Wallet.first
amount = wallet.operations.sum(:amount)
```

Answer (score 1):

Question is slightly ambiguous. Assuming you have an instance of Kit named as **kit**, and a kit has many **product** objects; following would get you the desired result.

```
sum = 0
kit_id = <enter kit id here>
kit = Kit.find_by_id(kit_id)

# iterate through every product object and compound price here
kit.products.each{|product| sum = sum + product.price} 

puts sum
```

Basically you need to iterate through every product object and compute the sum, since it's a has many relationship.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Vasanth, I finally used the selected Answer that worked in a cleaner way!

Answer (score 1):

This will give you every kit with the sum of it's products, i assume there is a column named name in your kit model

```
@kit_products_price = Kit.includes(:products).group(:name).sum('products.price')
```

If you want the sum of all the kit products :

```
@kit_price = Kit.includes(:products).sum('products.price')
```

Answer (score 0):

The following should work I believe:

Active Record collection

```rb
@total = kit.products.sum("price")
```

Ruby array

```rb
@total = kit.products.sum(&:price)
```